# Nagios: How to properly configure NRPE to monitor IMAP and SMTP

Tags: smtp, imap, nagios, zimbra, nrpe

We would like to monitor the IMAP and SMTP services on our Zimbra server through Nagios. I have the following two lines configured in my nrpe.cfg file on the Zimbra server:

```
command[check_imap]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_imap -H <hostname> -p 993
command[check_smtp]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_smtp -H <hostname> -p 465
```

And here is are the corresponding services in services.cfg on the Nagios server:

```
define service {
    use generic-service
    host_name <hostname>
    service_description IMAP
    check_command check_nrpe!check_imap
}

define service {
    use generic-service
    host_name <hostname>
    service_description SMTP
    check_command check_nrpe!check_smtp
}
```

We keep getting "CHECK_NRPE: socket timeout after 10 seconds" errors when trying to monitor these services. We use SSL on the Zimbra server, so I assume I need ports 993 and 465 defined in the command line. All of the other services we monitor (disk SMART status, processes, etc.) are fine. What else can I check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mea culpa. You have to add the -S switch to the end of the command lines to tell Nagios to use SSL to monitor those services.

I also changed the SMTP port from 465 to 587. Both services are are now displaying properly in Nagios.